# On Google Form Submit clear cells of active row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm quite new to google sheet script and looking for some assistance.  I am trying to make a google script that will erase cells in a response sheet after a user has submitted it.  As this could be a form edit url, it may not necessarily be the last row.

So everytime a form is submitted / edited, columns AN:AQ are cleared.

Any help greatly appreciated

---

I'm adding the working script to OP's question for anyone who comes across this.

```
function onFormSubmit11(e) { 
   var range = e.range; 
   var ss = range.getSheet(); 
   var row = range.getRowIndex(); 

ss.getRange("AN"+row).clear(); 
ss.getRange("AO"+row).clear(); 
ss.getRange("AP"+row).clear() 
ss.getRange("AQ"+row).clear() 
}
```

Comment: Are you adding the trigger on the destination spreadsheet or on the form? The structure of the event object is dependent on your choice.

Answer (score 0):

The Spreadsheet trigger invoked by the Google Form contains the Range object. You can retrieve the sheet linked to the range as well the index of the row linked to the current form submission.

```
function formTrigger(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var rowIndex = row.getRowIndex();
  sheet.getRange(rowIndex + 1, 1).setValue("Hello");
}
```

Comment: Hi Amit,

Thank you.

I've added the code and added the script to the project's triggers to run on form submit.  There does not seem to be "Hello" in any cell?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try something as simple as an onFormSubmit running the script through your linked spreadsheet. The script below will clear AN:AQ every time a form is submitted which is 'alf of what I think you're asking for.

As for on **edit**, that's something I'm trying to figure out myself in my own question!

```
function onFormSubmit() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sh = ss.getActiveSheet()

sh.getRange('AN1:AQ').clear();

}
```

---

Hi Again,

Try this below. As before, make sure your trigger is set on OnFormSubmit and it should work flawlessly. I've tested it myself, it only cleared the range between AN:AQ on row (wherever the form edits). If you want to delete different sections just replace the AN:AQ for whatever column(s) you wish to clear.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

var range = e.range;
var ss = range.getSheet();
var row = range.getRowIndex(); 

ss.getRange("AN:AQ"+row).clear();

}
```

Comment: Hi Rich,

Thank you - i tried the above code which worked and it cleared all data in AN1:AQ... however I am looking to clear the data only in the row that contains the responses of the modified form.

Comment: I edited my original answer, should work perfectly. Even if it's not the bottom row!

Comment: Hmmmm.. i've updated the script but I'm afraid nothing is clearing....  thanks for trying

Comment: what did you do to update it, just pasted over the old one?

Comment: @NiugeS Try this, open your response sheet, tools -> script editor. Paste the above script into the script editor (my 2nd version) . Go to Edit - Current Project triggers. Click onFormSubmit from the drop down, From Spreadsheet, onFormSubmit. hit ok, then go submit a form/edit an existing response. should auto run.

Comment: Yes just copied over the original... double check the trigger was set correctly as well..

Comment: @NiugeS Sometimes On triggers can bug out, also try removing the trigger completely, File -> manage versions, save new version, then put the trigger back on.

Comment: good news and bad news!  The script is now executing when the form is submitted (thank you!) but it is deleting data in multiple rows... if i change your ocde ss.getRange("AN"+row).clear(); it works perfectly... but i need it do to the 3 next columns as well..  Is it possible "AN:AQ"+row needs to be different?

Comment: I changed the code to the following and it works.. i'm sure there is an easier way:

}
function onFormSubmit11(e) {
var range = e.range;
var ss = range.getSheet();
var row = range.getRowIndex(); 
ss.getRange("AN"+row).clear();
ss.getRange("AO"+row).clear();
ss.getRange("AP"+row).clear()
ss.getRange("AQ"+row).clear()
}

Comment: My guess is that maybe my code was deleting data underneath, didn't think of that, i was testing on the bottom row. At least you got there, no worries dude